# How to create major and minor gridlines with different linestyles

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridlines

I am currently using `matplotlib.pyplot` to create graphs and would like to have the major gridlines solid and black and the minor ones either greyed or dashed.

In the grid properties, `which=both/major/mine`, and then color and linestyle are defined simply by linestyle. Is there a way to specify minor linestyle only?

The appropriate code I have so far is

```
plt.plot(current, counts, 'rd', markersize=8)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid(b=True, which='both', color='0.65', linestyle='-')
```

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Actually, it is as simple as setting `major` and `minor` separately:

```
In [9]: plot([23, 456, 676, 89, 906, 34, 2345])
Out[9]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x6112f90>]

In [10]: yscale('log')

In [11]: grid(b=True, which='major', color='b', linestyle='-')

In [12]: grid(b=True, which='minor', color='r', linestyle='--')
```

The gotcha with minor grids is that you have to have minor tick marks turned on too.  In the above code this is done by `yscale('log')`, but it can also be done with `plt.minorticks_on()`.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes you also need to call `plt.minorticks_on()` for the minor grid to actually appear. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940830/209246

Comment: From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html): "If kwargs are supplied, it is assumed that you want a grid and b is thus set to True." - so you might omit `b=True`.

Comment: I have tried doing the same with double log plot. Unfortunately the x-axis shows only the major thicks. Is it possible to switch on also the minor thicks.

Comment: ＠Alexander you need to add `axis="both"` parameter to the `plt.grid()` function.

Comment: Is there a rcParam property to make this as the default style ?

Comment: To whom who may use this answer with Matplotlib 3.5+: the 'b' parameter of grid() has been renamed 'visible'

Answer (score 24):

A simple DIY way would be to make the grid yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([1,2,3], [2,3,4], 'ro')

for xmaj in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs():
  ax.axvline(x=xmaj, ls='-')
for xmin in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklocs():
  ax.axvline(x=xmin, ls='--')

for ymaj in ax.yaxis.get_majorticklocs():
  ax.axhline(y=ymaj, ls='-')
for ymin in ax.yaxis.get_minorticklocs():
  ax.axhline(y=ymin, ls='--')
plt.show()
```