# Why are minor gridlines not appearing

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am having difficult trying to get minor gridlines to appear on a plot. I have seen a couple of SO questions on this, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127434/how-to-create-major-and-minor-gridlines-with-different-linestyles-in-python) suggesting two grid objects (one for major and one for minor) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940518/cannot-get-minor-grid-lines-to-appear-in-matplotlib-figure) suggesting also adding `minorticks_on`.

For some reason the minor gridlines are still not appearing when I use the code below, can anyone shed any light please:

```
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import log, sqrt

x = range(1, 20)
x_lin = x
x_log = [log(i) for i in x]

x2 = [sqrt(i) for i in x]
x2_exp = x

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
p1 = ax.plot(x, x_lin, 'g--', label='linear', linewidth=2)
p2 = ax.plot(x, x_log, 'b-', label='log', linewidth=3)
p3 = ax.plot(x2, x2_exp, 'r-', label='exp', linewidth=3)
l1 = ax.legend()
g1 = ax.grid(b=True, which='both', color='k', linestyle='-')
g2 = ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='--')
ax.minorticks_on
plt.show()
```

Here is what I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change: `ax.minorticks_on` to  `ax.minorticks_on()`

Answer (score 4):

Following the answer given by @M4rtini here is the corrected code and new image:

```
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import log, sqrt

x = range(1, 20)
x_lin = x
x_log = [log(i) for i in x]

x2 = [sqrt(i) for i in x]
x2_exp = x

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
p1 = ax.plot(x, x_lin, 'g--', label='linear', linewidth=2)
p2 = ax.plot(x, x_log, 'b-', label='log', linewidth=3)
p3 = ax.plot(x2, x2_exp, 'r-', label='exp', linewidth=3)
l1 = ax.legend()
g1 = ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
g2 = ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.2)
ax.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

[image]