# Get grid points from matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the coordinates of map of india. x-axis range is 65 to 100 and y-axis range is 0-100. I have generated grid in this range. I want to get the coordinates of the grid plot. how can i get that?

```
 #!usr/bin/env python
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 f = np.loadtxt('New_Coordinate.txt')
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.gca()
 ax.set_xticks(np.arange(65,100,1))
 ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,100,1))
 plt.plot(f[:,:1],f[:,1:],'ro')
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, what do you want exactly? a list of (x,y) points in which the grid lines meet?

Comment: IMVHO one hundred ticks (or even 65) is too much ticks on a single axis... consider that you can have major and minor ticks, the latter possibly w/o labels, and hence avoiding a lot of clutter on your plot. See for examples http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127434/how-to-create-major-and-minor-gridlines-with-different-linestyles-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The grid points are created at the locations of the tick marks on both axes.

You can then use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all of the pairs of those points which would be where the grid lines intersect.

```
import itertools

xticks = ax.get_xticks()
yticks = ax.get_yticks()

gridpoints = list( itertools.product(xticks, yticks) )
```