# How to change the interval spacing within the x axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, intervals, graphing

Let us say I have code as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



x = np.arange(0.2,0.3,0.01)    
y = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(x,y,)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

It will produce this graph:
￼[image]

How could I change my code so the x axis has a less visible grid every given interval, say 0.02?

Comment: This seems to be a dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127434/how-to-create-major-and-minor-gridlines-with-different-linestyles-in-python

Comment: If this is not a dublicate of the above mentionned question, you need to more specific on your question.